# how to change timestamp format in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to change the current 24 hr format like 22:16:08 to something like 10:16:08 in mysql?
I want to change how these values are saved. Is it possible or I will just let php handle things for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't change the way how these values are *saved*. Change the way they are *output*.

See [`TIME_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)

In your case, this would show a `TIME` field as `10:16:08 PM`:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(timefield, "%l:%i:%s %p") AS date_formatted;
```

Comment: if I do this, would the way of fetching records be different?SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')FROM reports  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){

echo $row['DATE'];
}

Comment: @Ieyasu good point. I modified the example query. If you give it an alias using `AS`, you will be able to access it using `echo $row["date_formatted"];`

Answer (score 1):

You should always store date/time values in their native format, which in MySQL is the 24hr format. You can change how they're retrieved with

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(somedatetimefield, 'format string here')
FROM table
```

where the format string options are defined [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

If doing that manually for every query is a problem, you can always create a view to do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't change how the data is saved in MySQL. Instead you should only present it differently. You can use PHP's `date` function to format the date in anyway you want. This is a huge advantage because you are separating how the data is saved and how the data is presented.

Comment: ok thanks for the ideas, I'll just use php then. Together with the datetime type

Answer (score 1):

Using [DATEFORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) you can save/fetch the date how you wish (much like PHP `date()`'s syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Like Pekka said: Don't change the way how these values are saved.

You can also easily handle this in php using `date()`

like `date("hh:ii:ss")`
This puts out the format you used in your example. (which is 12-hours format and leading zeros.)