# MySQL replace a character with a space

Tags: mysql, replace

WOW... Using MySQL, is there a way to replace the third "-" from the left in the following timestamp:

2012-06-05-23:48:10

You'd think after an hour of searching I would have found something..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal replace operation that you describe is probably beyond the abilities of pure mySQL - it has [regex capabilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), but only for matching.

However, one workaround comes to mind:

- Convert the field into a DATETIME field using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- then output it using a custom format using [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

that said, storing the date as a native `DATETIME` field in the first place would be a good idea anyway.

Comment: It was actually much easier. I changed the structure of my 'date' column to `TIMESTAMP`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (based on your suggestion) and the third dash was removed automatically from all rows.

Answer (score 0):

For this, it makes more sense for the data to be saved using the standard but given back as the way your application would use it. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805447/how-to-change-timestamp-format-in-mysql) explains what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL is a relational database management system; it's not for manipulating data.

Instead you would use a programing or scripting language like php to query the database, pull the data into a string, change it, and update the databse. Edit: I'm told that this is possible, but as another user stated there's no direct solution in pure MySQL.