# MySQL from timestamp int to yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ

Tags: mysql

I want to convert an int column which represents a timestamp to a varchar column which represents the date in yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ format.

I want to use only MySQL query.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change timestamp format in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805447/how-to-change-timestamp-format-in-mysql)

Comment: @defaultlocale Not a duplicate. The question you suggested as duplicate is about the datatype timestamp. Different story. We're talking about integer here, representing a unix timestamp. FYI: You can retreat your close vote.

Comment: @fancyPants VTC retracted, thanks for correction! I misunderstood this question initially, but I still suspect it was already asked here. Probably somebody else will find a valid duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

> FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp), FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp,format)
>
> Returns a representation of the unix_timestamp argument as a value in
>   'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on
>   whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. The value
>   is expressed in the current time zone. unix_timestamp is an internal
>   timestamp value such as is produced by the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function.
>
> If format is given, the result is formatted according to the format
>   string, which is used the same way as listed in the entry for the
>   DATE_FORMAT() function.

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219);
        -> '2007-11-30 10:30:19'
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219) + 0;
        -> 20071130103019.000000
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
    ->                      '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x');
        -> '2007 30th November 10:30:59 2007'
```

> Note: If you use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and FROM_UNIXTIME() to convert
>   between TIMESTAMP values and Unix timestamp values, the conversion is
>   lossy because the mapping is not one-to-one in both directions. For
>   details, see the description of the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function.